# Setting NumericUpDown to read only

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

I have a NumericUpDown on one of the pages of my program and its name is R1G.

In my code, I am trying to declare this NumericUpDown as read-only, so that users can only alter its number value by using the arrow keys at the side rather than entering their own number values.

The problem is, every time I try to enter R1G as read only, Visual Studio gives my coding line an error which says 'Declaration expected'

I have tried each of these one-line alternatives:

`NumericUpDown.ReadOnly = true`
`R1G.NumericUpDown.ReadOnly = true`
`R1G.ReadOnly = true`
`R1G.Text.ReadOnly = true`

but to no avail. I can't think of any other way I can set R1G as read only. Can you help?

Strangely enough, I did edit the code so now the line R1G.Readonly=True
is there, however, R1G is in red underline and 'Declaration expected' still appears?

Comment: `R1G.ReadOnly = True`, that is all you should have to do... `Visual Studio gives my coding line an error`, what line is this?

Comment: Is this a Winforms project? Assuming R1G is a NumericUpDown control, you should be able to do `R1G.Readonly=True`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to maintain the white backcolor (not appear as disabled/readonly) you can simply suppress key press in the KeyDown event

```
Private Sub NumericUpDown1_KeyDown(sender As Object, e As KeyEventArgs) Handles NumericUpDown1.KeyDown
    e.SuppressKeyPress = True
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I turned out that I could not simply edit the NumericUpDown properties to read-only through using the coding window, but rather I was able to toggle a False/True setting for each NumericUpDown's read-only setting through using their properties window within Visual Studio. Now, I have set all of my NumericUpDown read-only properties to True, and this prevents a user from typing in their own values or leaving them blank! :)